# Castle Active Record Session Scope vs Transaction Scope & Connection Management

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, database-connection, castle-activerecord

All,

In Nhibernate I saw a lot of code written as:

```
using(ISession sess = factory.OpenSession()) {
 using(ITransaction trans = sess.BeginTransaction()) {
    // query, or save
    trans.Commit();
```

}}

Starting transactions for queries or even single entity update always puzzled me why? Then after reading I learned that if you follow this pattern you will get 2 benefits:

1. Automatic connection release
2. Automatic flush

Fair enough. 
My question is in regards to Castle ActiveRecord and connection pooling.

I am using Active Record in ASP.NET app, and the common pattern is to create a session for entire request.

My questions are:

1.
Should I use SessionScope or TransactionScope (and use start/end transaction to get/release my connection) so that I achieve efficient connection pooling,- ie. I want to hold on to the database connection (ADO.net connection object) during my persistence logic only, not for the entire life-time of the request (use connection semantics that are implemented by nhibernate transactions mentioned above)?

2.
Does SessionScope flushes when it goes out of scope (ie. in its Dispose method)?

LK (Answered): Yes, unless the scope is read-only.

3.
Does TransactionScope rollback when it goes out of scope (ie. in its Dispose method)?

LK (Answered): Depends on onDispose action, but by default it commits.

4.
Where's the official Castle Active Record documentation, - I see bits and pieces on various sites and various sites with broken links. Is there an official PDF documentation like for nhibernate or even a book?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SessionScope.  It will handle the common transaction semantics for you.  You can use a TransactionScope when you need more fine grained control on the transaction.  You can even open a TransactionScope within a SessionScope to handle multiple transactions within a single session.

The official documentation is here:
http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.MainPage.ashx

It is not great.
The old documentation is here:
http://old.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/index.html

The old stuff is better for some topics.